# Two questions about a proof on this site: show $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/n}}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}} \,dx = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis

Please see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2266612/51407

I want to know why $f_{n}(x)=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{( 1+ \frac{x}{n})^{n}} \le \frac{1}{x^{2}}$?

Also, the choice of the domaninating function $g$ is a bit confusing. I can see that if $x \in [M, \infty)$ then $|f_{n}| \le g$, but I don't why if $x \in (0, M)$  then $|f_{n}| \le g$.

EDIT: I have copied the linked proof by user [Giovanni](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/263115/giovanni) below:

> Notice that the pointwise limit of the integrands is $e^{-x}$. Moreover, notice that for $M \ge 1$ large enough $$f_n(x) = \frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n} \le \frac{1}{x^2}.$$ Then $$g(x) = 
> \begin{cases}M & \text{if}\ x\in (0,M)\\
> \frac{1}{x^2} & \text{if}\ x\in [M,\infty)
> \end{cases}$$ is integrable and satisfies $|f_n| \le g$ in $(0,\infty)$. By Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, $$\lim_n\int_0^{\infty}f_n\,dx = \int_0^{\infty}\lim_nf_n\,dx = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\,dx = 1.$$

Comment: Is it possible to use an alternative option for the dominating function?

Comment: On the interval $x\in[0;n]$
$$\frac1{1+\frac xn}=1-\frac xn+\frac {x^2}{n^2}-...=1-\frac xn+\frac {x^2}{n^2}\left(1-\frac xn+\frac {x^2}{n^2}-...\right)=1-\frac xn+\frac xn\frac {\frac xn}{1+\frac xn}$$
$$\leqslant1-\frac xn+\frac xn\cdot\frac12=1-\frac x{2n}$$
$$\frac {x^{\frac1n}}{\big(1+\frac xn)^n}\leqslant x^\frac1n\big(1-\frac x{2n}\big)^n=x^\frac1n e^{n\ln(1-\frac x{2n})}=x^\frac1n e^{n\big(-\frac x{2n}-\frac {x^2}{8n^2}-...\big)}\leqslant n^\frac1ne^{-\frac x2}\leqslant e^\frac1ee^{-\frac x2}$$
as $n^\frac1n$ reaches its maximum at $n=e$ .

Comment: Therefore, we can take as a dominating function $f(x)=e^\frac1ee^{-\frac x2}$ on the interval $x\in[0;\infty)$ and consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac {x^{\frac1n}}{\big(1+\frac xn)^n}\bf{1}_{[0;n]}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav: I'm interested in an explanation for the original question, but don't mind seeing alternatives either, and I like your answer a lot.

You should leave your work as an answer also.

Comment: For $x\in[0;1] \,\frac{\frac xn}{1+\frac xn}$ reaches the maximum at $x=n;\, \max_{x\in[0;n]}\frac{\frac xn}{1+\frac xn}=\frac12$. Therefore,
$$\frac xn\frac{\frac xn}{1+\frac xn}\leqslant\frac xn\cdot\frac12$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav: Yes you're right, thank you!